# Embed kml tool deprecated?

Tags: web, google-earth

HI I am trying to embed google earth map in my website at the moment, but because the "embed kml tool has been deprecated" I am unsure of how to do so ? I have tried using fake embed kml tools, but they don't seem to work as they are relying on Google APIs. 
Has anyone had similar experience in embedding google earth in html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google Earth Plugin javascript API still works for now.  Google even has "adapter" code that will let you place an "Earth" toggle button next to the "Map" and "Satellite" toggles and sync a Google Map javascript API V3 implementation to the Google Earth plugin.  I've got it working even now on my own website, and I put it together only two months ago.

However, it will stop working in December this year, so I know I'm going to have to replace that.  You should note that the new Google Maps My Maps engine (aka Google Maps Engine Lite) now has a native Earth mode instead of a Satellite mode.  It is widely hoped that Google will soon release a Google Maps javascript API V4 that accesses this new maps engine, and give everyone a more uniform API interface to both Maps and Earth (and is consistent with the Mobile API implementations)

So for now, if you are just learning and the map added to your site is not critical long-term, go ahead and use the Google Earth plugin API to learn how to use both Maps and Earth APIs even together.  It really won't be time wasted.  But you will have to rework and replace it before year's end.

If however you are building something long-term for a customer or that map is the key aspect of your site, you should start researching alternatives.  There are all sorts of discussions and recommendations (just do a search) and Google itself is making recommendations to use other (non-free) replacement products for commercial uses.

And keep watching Google's own developer's site for announcements about the APIs.  Likely there will soon be a way to access the new Earth interface.